# Dart / Flutter Page Not Reloading After SetState?

Tags: dart, state, flutter, ternary

I have a follow / unfollow button that changes the UI depending on the value of a public string.  The problem is after the value of the String has changed and setState is called the UI remains the same. If I reload the page then it may change.  Here is my code...

```
var friends;

Future<Null> follow() async{
friends = "Friends"
setState((){});
}

Future<Null> unfollow() async{
friends = "Not Friends"
setState((){});
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
          title: new Text(
            'Friends',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: new Container(


         // Unfollow and Message

                friends == "Friends" ? new RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: unfollow,
                      child: new Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Icon(
                            Icons.not_interested,
                          ),
                          new Text(
                            "UNFOLLOW",
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ) :

                  new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: follow,
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Icon(
                        Icons.thumb_up,
                      ),
                      new Text(
                        "FOLLOW",
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

I'm trying to show either a follow or unfollow RaisedButton depending on the value of "friends" and its not working.  I'm not sure if it's the way I'm setting my State or if my Ternary operator is written incorrectly.  Please help!

Comment: just curious, why do you use `async` for your onclick callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the state, add your logic inside `setState()` method. Anyway, when I'm looking at your code, I don't think you need to use `async`, but you can change it back.

```
void unfollow(){
  setState(() =>friends = "Not Friends");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't actually matter whether or not you set a field inside of the setState closure or outside.

Answer (score 2):

setState will only work for stateful widget but not stateless widget
Is it a stateful widget..?

I had added answer please check out

```
 void main() {
   runApp(new samplea());
  }

  class samplea extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_sampleaState createState() => new _sampleaState();
 }

class _sampleaState extends State<samplea> {
 var friends;

   follow() {
  friends = "Friends";
   setState(() {});
   }

    unfollow(){
  friends = "Not Friends";
  setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
        ),
        body: new Container(
            child: friends == "Friends"
                ? new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: unfollow,
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                          Icons.not_interested,
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          "UNFOLLOW",
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                : new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: follow,
                    child: new Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Icon(
                          Icons.not_interested,
                        ),
                        new Text(
                          "FOLLOW",
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ))));
  }
  }
```

Comment: Yes. It's a Stateful Widget. I just condensed my code. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please share the complete stateful widget class

Comment: please check my edited answer it will solve ur problem